# My function doesn't return an entire sentence

Tags: python, function

So I'm trying to learn python better and i've been using this website http://www.learnpython.org/

I'm on to functions right now, heres the code

```
#Add your functions here (before the existing functions) 

def list_benefits():
    myList = ['More organized code','More readable code','Easier code reuse','Allowing     programmers to share and connect code together']
    return myList

def build_sentence(info):
    addMe = " is a benefit of functions!"
    for i in info:
        meInfo = i + addMe
    return meInfo
        
    
def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print build_sentence(benefit)

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```

the output being

> e is a benefit of functions!
>
> e is a benefit of functions!
>
> e is a benefit of functions!
>
> r is a benefit of functions!

What am i missing to return the whole scentence

Comment: There's no OOP in your question.

Comment: Was going to fix it but tMC got it for me, thanks tMC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside  `def build_sentence(info):`

No need to loop over `info` since you'll get character by character.

```
def build_sentence(info):
    addMe = " is a benefit of functions!"
    return info + addMe
```

Also
In this part:

```
for i in info:
        meInfo = i + addMe
    return meInfo
```

You are setting up meInfo every time in the loop constantly changing that value.
At the end you are just returning the last value you got from the loop

Answer (score 2):

Your `build_sentence()` function iterates over the string passed to it, and binds each letter plus the other string in turn to `meInfo`. After it finishes with the last letter, it returns the value. The fix is to stop iterating over the string and instead just add the whole thing and return.

Comment: could you explain that to someone who doesn't understand the lingo quite well?

Comment: `>>> for c in 'foo!': print c`
`... `
`f`
`o`
`o`
`!`

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print build_sentence(benefit)
```

you call build_sentence() with a string argument.  build_sentence then iterates over the characters in the string, with the effect that you see.

Instead, call build_sentence passing the *entire list*.  This will iterate over the *list*, attaching the extra text to each item in the list (not each character in a string).

```
def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    print build_sentence(list_of_benefits)
```

Also, inside build_sentence, you create and then throw away the text created from each list item, returning only the last item and extra text.  If you want to print each one you can either move the `print` statement *inside* the build_sentence() function (and probably rename it to print_sentence() or you can create a list inside that function and return the list:

```
def build_sentence(info):
    addMe = " is a benefit of functions!"
    result = []
    for i in info:
        result.append(i + addMe)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into here is that your `build_sentence()` is taking an argument (each call is with a single string) but iterating over that and only returning the last result (thus it returns a sentence containing the last character of the string with the rest of the statically defined sentence).

If you iterate over a string then you'll be handing each character of the string.

Something like:

```
def build_sentence(benefit):
    '''Returns a sentence from a template filling in benefit as the subject'''
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!' % benefit
```

... will work with the rest of your code.

Alternatively you could have a `build_sentences()` function like:

```
def build_sentences(*benefits):
    '''Returns a list of sentences from a template touting each benefit'''
    results = list()
    for each in benefits:
        results.append("%s is a benefit if functions!" % each)
    return results
```

... and then simplt call that function one with a list of the benefits like:

```
build_sentences('More organized code','More readable code','Easier code reuse','Allowing programmers to share and connect code together')
```

... or

```
build_sentences(*myList)
```

This particular form (using `*benefits` as the parameters for the function definition, an either supplying a variable number of arguments to the function call, or using the `*myList` form to expand the contents of my list, applying that list into the "varargs" argument list is a little more advanced.  (It's also not strictly necessary for this case, you could remove the `*` prefix from both the function's parameter definition and the function's calling arguments.  In that case when calling the function with a literal list of benefits you'd have to wrap the literal string argument in `[...]` to make them into a literal string:

```
def tout_benefits(benefits):
    '''Given a list of benefits tout them using a template'''
    return [ "%s is a benefit of functions!" % x for x in benefits ]

tout_benefits(['More organized code','More readable code','Easier code reuse','Allowing programmers to share and connect code together'])
# Notice called with `[ ..., ..., ... ]`
```

Also notice, in this last form, I reduced the `for ...` loop into a more compact "list comprehension" ... and expression returning a list.  I could have used that form in the previous example as well; but wanted to introduce it separately from making the point about varargs (variable parameter/arguments) handling.

Also note that you could use `+` expressions in place of `"%s ..." %` for all of these examples.  However, the "string formatting" operator gives you considerably more control of exactly how values are interpolated into your template/strings and allows for multiple values, types, numeric precisions, and a number of other features far beyond simple string concatenation (using `+`).

Answer (score 0):

Modify this function to return a list of strings as defined above:

```
def list_benefits():
    return "More organized code", "More readable code", "Easier code reuse", "Allowing programmers to share and connect code together"

def build_sentence(info):
    return "%s is a benefit of functions!"% (info)
```

Modify this function to concatenate to each benefit - " is a benefit of functions!":

```
def name_the_benefits_of_functions():
    list_of_benefits = list_benefits()
    for benefit in list_of_benefits:
        print build_sentence(benefit)

name_the_benefits_of_functions()
```